# Objective C: How to use CGLayerCreate and CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, core-graphics

I am studying Core Graphics to make dynamic textures for my project.

A friend told me that i should use CGLayerCreate and CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint
to improve the texture of the brush app that i am building but i haven't found any book or tutorial that includes CGLayerCreate and CGContextDrawAtPoint.

can you guys tell what's the use of this two and how will able to code them?

also if you know any core graphics book that includes those please tell me, it'll surely help me.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH219-TPXREF101) has a chapter that discusses `CGLayer` objects.

Your friend might be thinking of this use of layers, quoting that chapter:

> Repeated drawing. For example, you might want to create a pattern that
>   consists of the same item drawn over and over. Draw the item to a
>   layer and then repeatedly draw the layer, as shown in Figure 12-1. Any
>   Quartz object that you draw repeatedly—including CGPath, CGShading,
>   and CGPDFPage objects—benefits from improved performance if you draw
>   it to a CGLayer. Note that a layer is not just for onscreen drawing;
>   you can use it for graphics contexts that aren’t screen-oriented, such
>   as a PDF graphics context.

There's also a very very simple example in the [*Quartz2DBasics*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Quartz2DBasics/Listings/CommonCode_AppDrawing_c.html) sample app.

Comment: the example is for Mac and it's not running, i need it on iOS.